# Trying to use htaccess in subdirectory to change url to lowercase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We just moved from a IIS server to Apache and we are trying to get our links working with Apache's case sensitivity. We have a ton of pages,so I'm going directory by directory making the changes. I'm testing it first to make sure it works. I'm adding a `.htaccess` file to covert incoming urls to lower case. I'm using the following because I don't want to mess with the httpd.config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /advertising/

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

As you can see I'm testing this in the `advertising` directory, but it keeps redirecting the links to the root folder. I clear the cached and check again, even used another computer to test. Urls still converted to the root directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a leading slash before `/$1`, which makes it ignore the RewriteBase. Also, you don't need the slash in the pattern. Just use `^(.*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use relative URI in your last redirect i.e.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bible/

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2 [L]

# If there are no uppercase letters left, redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =200
RewriteRule ^((?!.*[A-Z]).+)$ $1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: will this affect the subdomains in /advertising as well?

Comment: @mike When I tried this htaccess in a directory with a subdirectory, it gave me this error /folder/file.htm/file.htm/file.htm. Why? I need this to cover subdirectories as well.

Comment: What was the original URL before this redirect and what did it become after redirect? Test this in Chrome dev tool

Comment: In this example it was supposed to be: `http://www.tldm.org/bible/Old%20Testament/2kings.htm` and it went `http://www.tldm.org/bible/old%20testament/2kings.htm/2kings.htm/2kings.htm`.

Comment: If it is in `/bible/` sub-directory then why are you using `RewriteBase /advertising/`?